# If PHP echo code returns a value then run script. Else nothing

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code which returns the result I require inside of a tab. But because the JavaScript is in the same file it shows a blank tab when there is no data to show. I remove the JavaScript and the tab disappears. How can I run the JavaScript only if data is present so the tab will disappear? Or can I call it from another file?

```
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getData($this->getCode()));
?>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var commareplace = document.querySelectorAll("div > #bikefitment");
    for (var i = 0; i < commareplace.length; i++) {
        commareplace[i].innerHTML = commareplace[i].innerHTML.replace(/,/g, "<br />");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide your conditional logic in php that determines if there’s any data?

Comment: What is a tab for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to hide the tab if `escapeHtml()` returns empty value. So you can create a condition block to add the script if `escapeHtml()` returns a non-empty value.

```
<?php $EH = $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getData($this->getCode()));
if ($EH) {

echo $EH;
?>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var commareplace = document.querySelectorAll("div > #bikefitment");
    for (var i = 0; i < commareplace.length; i++) {
        commareplace[i].innerHTML = commareplace[i].innerHTML.replace(/,/g, "<br />");
    }
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge on PHP is not the best, so I will just describe it like that.

- Just save the data in a variable
- If the data exists (e.g. is not empty)

  - Print data and JavaScript code
- If it does not exist, do nothing

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
<?php
data = $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getData($this->getCode()));

if (data exists) {
    echo data;
    echo /* Your JavaScript Code*/;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a if statement that within the php tags that check value id present then you can render the the java script tags as well as the value.

```
<?php 
    $val = $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getData($this->getCode()));  
    $script =  '<script type="text/JavaScript">
                    var commareplace = document.querySelectorAll("div > #bikefitment");
                    for (var i = 0; i < commareplace.length; i++) {
                        commareplace[i].innerHTML = commareplace[i].innerHTML.replace(/,/g, "<br />");
                    }
                </script>';
    if($val != "" || $val !=null)
    { 
       echo $val; 
       echo $script;
    }
?>
```